# Which one is correct " God protect you" or " protects you"

Tags: expressions

When I wish someone a good thing, I would say:
God protects you.
But I have found all expressions that pray to God use verbs without "s".
Now I need to know what is the correct one.
God protects you and helps you.

Comment: Look up "subjunctive" to find out what is going on here.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive

Comment: Thanks, I got it, but it is "God protects you" is plain mistake?

Comment: Present indicative: God protects you.  Present subjunctive: God protect you.  Both are correct, but they have different meaning.

Comment: It is like 'God bless...' and not 'God blesses...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *God protect you*

This is a wish: ***may* God protect you**. When it comes to greetings, words are often omitted. It's like saying '*see you*', which is short for '*I hope to see you again (soon)*'.

> *God protects you*

This is the active form, implying that God is actively protecting you.
As a greeting it might be used as an **assurance or a reminder**.

Comment: “May the odds be ever in your favor” (from the _Hunger Games_ books) vs “The odds are in your favor”.  Greeting/wish vs simple statement of fact.

Comment: "May God protect you" is another way of saying "God protect you" not just a fuller version with omitted words reinstated. In the UK our national anthem begins with the words 'God save the Queen': a complete sentence in the subjunctive mood.

Comment: @JeremyC That's right. I like to think of these as "third-person imperatives". *Devil take the hindmost!*

Comment: Thank all of you, it's very informative.